# Can i "Promote" non users (in the identity sense) to user later down the road?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a graph of class, all inheriting from IdentityUser.

However in complex initialisations i'm getting issues (not looking for workaround, looking for a response to this specific question) when calling CreateUserAsync and also when trying to retrieve the data on my own context.

Is it possible to create my classes of type A B C D E etc all ultimately inherit from IdentityUser but add them to my own context with context.A.Add(my new A) instead of CreateUserAsync and then promote them to an identity user (tell identity framework to intiailize them with a password etc)?

Comment: By "graph of class" do you mean "graph of entity", i.e. [TPH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance)?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, like customer and employee both inheriting from user which itself inherits identityuser etc